# Loop to keep asking user for a sorted array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11

This time I have to make a program that asks the kind of search the user wants to use (Binary or  sequential), if Binary I have to ask the user to type a sorted array until it's sorted.

Here's the main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int n, decide, inicio, fin, key;

  cout << " ¿De que tamaño será tu Arreglo?: ";//What size your array will be?
  cin >> n;
  int arreglo[n]; // Create the array 

  cout << " ¿Qué tipo de Busqueda realizaremos hoy?\n\n";//What kind of search we will use?
  cout << "\n  1. Busqueda Secuencial.\n  2. Busqueda Binaria.\n\n";
  cin >> decide;

  cout << "\t\n- - Tu arreglo sera de " << n << " elementos. - -\n";//Your arry will be of "n" elements

  switch (decide) {
    case 1:
        inicializaLista(n, arreglo); // Fill the array.

        cout << "\n¿Que numero buscas?"; // Ask for the number we want to search.
        cin >> key;

        busquedaSecuencial(arreglo, n, key);
        break;

    case 2:
        inicio = 0;
        fin = n - 1;

        cout << "\nIngrese valores en orden\n";//Type sorted values
        inicializaLista(n, arreglo); // fill the array

        validarLista(n, arreglo); //validate List



        cout << "\n¿Que numero buscas?"; // Ask for the number we want to search.
        cin >> key;
        busquedaBinaria(arreglo, n, inicio, fin);

        break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my Validation function:

```
bool validarLista(int n, int arreglo[]) {

  cout << "Validando Lista ... ";

  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i] > arreglo[i + 1]) {
        return false; // It is proven that the array is not sorted.
    }
  }
  return true; // If this part has been reached, the array must be sorted.};
}
```

Here is where I fill the array

```
int inicializaLista(int n, int arreglo[]) {
  cout << "\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "Ingrese dato " << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> arreglo[i];
  }
};
```

I've done some "do-whiles" and tried with "if" and a lot of structures but can't get with the solution. How do I properly loop this so the Validation function keeps asking for a sorted array.
I'm sorry not translating all variables or anything in Spanish but if you could help me with this I would be so thankful.

Comment: I'm not C++, but shouldn't you convert the string input from cin to integer?

Comment: Rather than expecting the user to sort the array in order to input it, it would be less frustrating for the user to accept data in any order and for the program to sort the array if a binary search has been requested.

Comment: Yeah! I thought that but that's my teachers requirement, thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do {
    cout << "\nIngrese valores en orden\n";//Type sorted values
    inicializaLista(n, arreglo); // fill the array
} while (!validarLista(n, arreglo));
```

Comment: Thank You, It really worked, It works because the program will be initializing the array until the bool function returns other value than true, I guess.